# copy a specific item from one list to a specific place of another list by c#

Tags: c#

I have two lists like list1 and list2 both from type int. now I want to copy the item of index (2) in my list 1 and put it instead of item with index (3) in my second list. how is it possible?

```
list<int> list1 = new list<int>(){1,2,4,5,7,8,9,11};
list<int> list2 = new list<int>(){22,33,44,55,66};
```

I want to have the result as:

```
{22,33,44,4,66}
```

I did like this:

```
 list2[3]=list1[2];
```

but I have error of "`index out of range`"
I will really appreciate if help me.

Comment: Your example should work (except of the typo with `list` instead of `List). Did you tryed to run your example yourself?

Comment: Yes several times, I wrote it by myself, but still problem is existed

Comment: Your example works fine as it is; see Fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nipbbU.  You must be doing something different in your actual code.